# Toggle button isn`t working?(Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier )

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a problem with my code. I use a button to hide and show a menu but it isn't working. I didn't understand the problem.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  :: par. 3

```
$(function() {
  $(".but").click( {
    if $("#div").hasClass("class"){  //problem is here
      $("#div").removeClass("class").addClass("anotherclass");
    } else{
      $("#div").removeClass("anotherclass"").addClass("class");
    }
  });
});'
```

Comment: is that apostrophe at the end a typo?

Comment: You are missing `function()`. Please have a look at the example in the documentation, http://api.jquery.com/click/, it should be pretty clear from that.

Comment: it should be ``if($("#div").hasClass("class")){...``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said you're missing the function, also "but" is not a valid selector, and I added () in the if statement, but that's coding preference

```
$(function () {
    $("button").click(function () { //but is not valid selector, button is
        if ($("#div").hasClass("class")) { //problem is here
            $("#div").removeClass("class").addClass("anotherclass");
        } else {
            $("#div").removeClass("anotherclass").addClass("class");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but is one of my class I wrote it wrong. It was: (".but")

Comment: Thanks everyone who helped me, richbai90 it works.

Comment: If it worked for you please accept the answer.  O'm glad I was able to help. Unexpected identifier almost always means a syntax error somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Please check your console first, with the starting code you see:

> SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found '$' instead

start your debug from the console.

You are not assigning a handler to your click function because your are missing the `function()` key and you have a double `"` in your second `removeClass` and your if statement miss the enclosing parens.

Side note: `but` is a custom DOM tag if you want to select a class or an ID use the correct [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Code:

```
$(function() {
  $("but").click(function() {
    if ($("#div").hasClass("class")) {  //problem is here
      $("#div").removeClass("class").addClass("anotherclass");
    } else{
      $("#div").removeClass("anotherclass").addClass("class");
    }
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pmHsL/

Comment: AND ```but``` isn't a dom tag, so he probably means ```$("#but")```

Comment: @amenadiel it can be a custom tag (it's allowed), but considering the rest of the code can be a typo

Comment: I've read Addy Osmani's articles about custom tags, but I seriously doubt this is the case.

Comment: @amenadiel I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("but").click(function() {
        if $("#div").hasClass("class")){  //problem is here
            $("#div").removeClass("class").addClass("anotherclass");
        } else{
            $("#div").removeClass("anotherclass").addClass("class");
        }
    });
});
```

the `click` method uses an anonymous function, you left out `function()`. There was also a spare `"` on `anotherClass"`, and that `'` at the end is not needed either. And you're also missing a `)` on the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem in your code: when you use a "click" short-cut, you must pass a function, not an Object. Here is the solution:

```
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function(){
     $("#div").toggleClass("anotherclass class");
  });
});
```

Notice that the jQuery method "toggleClass" add the class ("anotherclass") if is doesn't  found it on the element ("#div"), and remove the class on the element if is already there.